# Python doesn't follow the 'if statement'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem with the python 2.7 code I made and can't seem to find any answers from friends so I came here.  I am a complete noob at python and programming in general.  Here is the code:

```
import time
import random
a = ['Spooky','Sexy','Snazzy','Random','Wild','Smoggy','Enchanting','Quick','Acoustic','Irritating','Annoying','Thirsty','Fierce','Embarassed','Touch']
b = ['Kurtis','Tisa','Randy','Theda','Dani','Beulah','Dallas','Jeannette','Vera','Kristopher','Donna','Wanda','Sergio','Betsy','Holly']
c = ['1873','123','448','8781','1284','3','45','34']
d = ['Hicks','Ryan','Houston','Cunningham','Ortiz','Baker','Erickson','Pittman','Patrick','Blake','Allison','Taylor','Harper','Romero']
random.shuffle(a)
random.shuffle(b)
random.shuffle(c)
random.shuffle(d)
a = raw_input('Would you like a random username? ')
if a == 'Yes' or 'yes' or 'Yea' or 'yea':
    print 'PROCESSING..'
    time.sleep(.5)
    print 'PROCESSING..'
    time.sleep(.5)
    print 'PROCESSING..'
    time.sleep(.5)
    print 'PROCESSING..'
    time.sleep(.5)
    print 'PROCESSING..'
    time.sleep(.5)
    print 'PROCESSING..'
    time.sleep(.5)
    print 'PROCESSING..'
    time.sleep(.5)
    print 'PROCESSING..'
    time.sleep(.5)
    print a[3] + b[2] + d[5] + c[4]
else:
    print "I didn't have a name for you anyways"
```

My problem is that the program generates a random name even if you enter something other then the 'Yes' or 'yes' or 'Yea' or 'yea'.
Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: In the future please include your code in the body of your post. I've edited to include it for you this time.

Comment: This is a common misunderstanding of how `or` works in Python. It's a duplicate question but I don't know what to search for.

Comment: It's a common misunderstanding of how logical OR works in pretty much every language.

Comment: @Adam it's especially problematic in Python since 1) it uses the word "or" for the operator implying that it works the same as the English language and 2) Python allows *anything* to be used in a boolean expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code checks `if a == 'Yes'`, and then `'yes'`, and then `'Yea'`, **and then** `'yea'`, which always results in entering the `if` statement because the string is nonempty.

Instead, change the `if` statement to `if a.lower().startswith('y'):`, as such:

```
import time
import random
a = ['Spooky','Sexy','Snazzy','Random','Wild','Smoggy','Enchanting','Quick','Acoustic','Irritating','Annoying','Thirsty','Fierce','Embarassed','Touch']
b = ['Kurtis','Tisa','Randy','Theda','Dani','Beulah','Dallas','Jeannette','Vera','Kristopher','Donna','Wanda','Sergio','Betsy','Holly']
c = ['1873','123','448','8781','1284','3','45','34']
d = ['Hicks','Ryan','Houston','Cunningham','Ortiz','Baker','Erickson','Pittman','Patrick','Blake','Allison','Taylor','Harper','Romero']
random.shuffle(a)
random.shuffle(b)
random.shuffle(c)
random.shuffle(d)
a = raw_input('Would you like a random username? ')
if a.lower().startswith('y'):
    print 'PROCESSING..'
    time.sleep(.5)
    print 'PROCESSING..'
    time.sleep(.5)
    print 'PROCESSING..'
    time.sleep(.5)
    print 'PROCESSING..'
    time.sleep(.5)
    print 'PROCESSING..'
    time.sleep(.5)
    print 'PROCESSING..'
    time.sleep(.5)
    print 'PROCESSING..'
    time.sleep(.5)
    print 'PROCESSING..'
    time.sleep(.5)
    print a[3] + b[2] + d[5] + c[4]
else:
    print "I didn't have a name for you anyways"
```

Comment: Take this question 'Would you like a random username?' and this answer 'yikes!' and ask yourself if checking for a 'y' at the start of the string is a good idea.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
if a in ['Yes', 'yes', 'Yea', 'yea']:
```

Each side of an `or` is its own independent expression. So if `a == 'Yes'` is false then Python will NOT try to see if `a == 'yes'` is true. It will try to see if `'yes'` is true. It is, because any non-empty string is considered true.

Answer (score 3):

Your code does the equivalent of this:

```
if (a == 'Yes') or ('yes') or ('Yea') or ('yea'):
    ...
```

`bool('yes')` is True - non-empty strings are considered True

Answer (score 2):

Your if condition is wrong, it should be

```
if a == 'Yes' or a == 'yes' or a == 'Yea' or a == 'yea':
```

Answer (score 2):

The 'or' operator doesn't work the way you think it does :)

When you have:

`if a == 'Yes' or 'yes' or 'Yea' or 'yea':`

your program will generate a random name if any of the following are true:

`a == 'Yes'
'yes'
'Yea'
'yea'`

A value like 'yes' or 'Yea' is always true, so your program will always generate a random name.

Either of the other answers is a good solution to your problem; the old-fashioned approach was something like:

`if a.upper()[0] == 'Y'`

which will accept any response that begins with 'y' or 'Y', which could be handy in case your users type 'Yep'!

Comment: If the OP implements your solution in a system, I would praise him for it! I would love to be able to type "yup" or "yepp...", and still have the program know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you write `if a == 'Yes' or 'yes' or 'Yea' or 'yea':`, it's indentical to `if (a == 'Yes') or ('yes') or ('Yea') or ('yea'):`. 'yes'/'Yea'/'yea' are evaluated as boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string    
if a.lower().startswith("y"):
```